# I can't click the "Crear" button through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

[image]

[image]

I tried with ActionChain, searching for shadow, frame, but nothing.

```
driver.get(Url)
time.sleep(5)

# Wait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 7, poll_frequency=1, ignored_exceptions=[
                     ElementNotVisibleException, ElementNotSelectableException])



pathBody = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '/html/body')))

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(pathBody)
hover.perform()
print('Funciona hover')


pathBody = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_5x"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[7]/div/span/div/a/div/div[1]/div/div/svg')))
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
> argument: 'value' must be a string   (Session info:
> chrome=117.0.5938.150)

Comment: linenumber of InvalidArgumentException ?